# Как искать однокоренные слова?

Tags: морфемный-разбор, недопустимая-метка, морфемика

Как искать однокоренные слова?

> пенал, корабль, письмо, осень, зима, огород, картофель, сарока, снегирь, воробей, дорога, тропа, осина, яблоня, малина, коллекция, малыш, погода, дерево, лагерь, молоток, овца, корова

Comment: Надо такой же корень сделать как и в слове.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы искать однокоренные слова, нужно, для начала, их грамотно писать. "Сорока" пишется через О.
А, вообще, каждое слово нужно видоизменить максимальное количество раз. И та его часть, которая везде останется неизменной (пусть даже это будет одна буква) и будет корнем слова. Также однокоренные слова близки по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет близких по смыслу слов не согласен. "Огород", "гражданин" и "город" - корень один, а смысл улавливается только через "ограду". А "гряда" (например, горная) тоже односмысленна с огородом?

Comment: Разумеется, "гряда" и "огород" несут близкую смысловую нагрузку: нечто огороженное или отгораживающее.

Answer (score 0):

Город и гражданин - полногласие и неполногласие: ла - оло, ра - оро,ре - ере, ле - еле. Так же как молоко - млеко. А подбирать как можно больше слов с максимально похожей частью.